# What is the value of project.build.finalName?

Tags: maven

The [*Maven* documentation](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/MavenPropertiesGuide) talks about a property called `project.build.finalName`, but I couldn't find a definition of the value it is set to based on other values in the `pom.xml`.

How is the value of `project.build.finalName` computed in absence of an overriding property definition in the `pom.xml`?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Google that...
Look at the Maven POM reference: http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#BaseBuild_Element

> **finalName**: This is the name of the bundled project when it is finally
>   built (sans the file extension, for example: my-project-1.0.jar). It
>   defaults to ${artifactId}-${version}. The term "finalName" is kind of
>   a misnomer, however, as plugins that build the bundled project have
>   every right to ignore/modify this name (but they usually do not). For
>   example, if the maven-jar-plugin is configured to give a jar a
>   classifier of test, then the actual jar defined above will be built as
>   my-project-1.0-test.jar.

Comment: When I am googling this is the first link!!

Comment: @qartal not surprising. That said, the POM reference material is relatively solid.

Comment: Yes, it is a misnomer. It should have been `finalBaseName`. One should file an issue and we will put this into consideration for model version 5.0.0.

Answer (score 15):

In the Eclipse Maven POM Editor, the "Effective POM" tab, you can see the value explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

In the IntelliJ Idea, Right-click on the project top folder and then click Maven => Show Effective POM to view the effective pom file. In that file, search for "finalName" to know it.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This seems to be a more recent feature of IntelliJ IDEA. I did not yet have a chance to get back to Java development.

Comment: This just uses `mvn help:effective-pom`, IntelliJ is only displaying the result.

Answer (score 2):

The final value is composed of the artifact groupId concatenated to the artifact id that you have declared in your pom.xml file

Comment: Is it `${groupId}-${artifactId}`?

Comment: Yes followed by the extension depending on the package type i.e war/jar/pom